# django rest framework multiple file upload issue "UnsupportedMediaType: Unsupported media type "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I am doing a multiple file upload call, with files and other metadata as part of form post

Frontend post call looks like:

```js
$http({
        url: "/images/add/",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        },
        data : data
      }).then(success, error);
```

On django backend it looks like:

```js
class ImageAdd(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print request.FILES['files']
```

On request.FILES['files'] it gives me error:

```
"UnsupportedMediaType: Unsupported media type "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Let me know if any more information is required

Comment: Can you change your content type header to /*/ and try again? Since you're also uploading a file, your content type shouldn't be application/json.

Comment: content type header to /*/ gives me error: detail unsupported media type "/*/" in request...

If I do 'Content-Type': undefined, then it gives me error: "detail unsupported media type "text/plain;charset=utf-8" in request."...

One more information I would like to give is data object looks something like: {"name":"filename", "files": Array[3]}

Comment: Here it says your media-type should be multipart/form-data. I've used FileUploadParser that's why I said try /*/. But for you, it should be multipart/form-data             http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser

Comment: Just to be sure, don't forget to add these into REST_FRAMEWORK in your settings.py file.        'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),

Comment: changing content type to  multipart/form-data, raises 400(Bad Request) from rest framework

Comment: Can you add your full code and also error traceback ?

Comment: Code and traceback are that much only, you can tell if anything more specific